# How to calculate how many people don't win prizes in a raffle?

Tags: probability

I'm not very experienced in probability or percentages so forgive me if I this question is elementry. If you buy a raffle ticket, you can win a computer or 1 of 10 tablets. If you purchase 1 ticket, the probability of winning a tablet is 1/7. How many tickets win no prizes? No other information is stated, is this enough to answer the question?

Answer (score 1):

Assume that all the prizes have been handed out, i.e. 1 computer and 10 tablets. Exactly 1/7 of people got a tablet, so there must be 70 people overall. So, there are 70 - 1 - 10 = 59 tickets that win no prizes.

Comment: I'd extend your answer to respond to the last question, "Is this enough to answer the question?"   Note you don't have to assume all the prizes were handed out since the question is solely about the tickets, not about the tickets bought.